# Python 3.5.1, the global variable is not destroyed when delete the module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyobject

I have a app loading python35.dll. Use python API PyImport_AddModule to run a py file. And use PyDict_DelItemString to delete the module. There is a global vailable in the py file. The global variable is not destroyed when calling PyDict_DelItemString to delete the module. The global variable is destroyed when calling Py_Finalize. It's too late. That cause the memory leak. Because the Py_Initialize is called at the app startup, the Py_Finalize is called at the app shutdown.

But it is ok with python33.dll, the global variable can be destroyed when calling PyDict_DelItemString to delete the module.

How to resolve the problem? Is there a workaround? I need to use python35.dll and wish the global variable in a module can be released automatically when call PyDict_DelItemString to delete the module.

Here is the python test code:

```
class Simple:  
     def __init__( self ):  
         print('Simple__init__')
     def __del__( self ):  
         print('Simple__del__') 

simple = Simple()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved. Need to call PyGC_Collect after PyDict_DelItemString with Python post 3.4 versions.

For detailed info, please read http://bugs.python.org/issue28202.